# How to give user specific access to BigQuery columns?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently trying to limit the columns that my view may return but keeping the possibility to the user to filter it, for example:

**Table**

{ f_name: string, l_name: string, ssn: string }

**View**

{ f_name: string, l_name: string}

but allowing queries like this: SELECT * FROM view WHERE ssn = '1234567890'

I am pretty sure that there is better approach but I am too deep to see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is high level idea for you
This is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 'a' f_name, 'x' l_name, '1234567890' ssn UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'y', '2234567890' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 'z', '3234567890' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', 'v', '4234567890' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'r', 'w', '5234567890' 
),
`yourView`AS (
  SELECT f_name, l_name, FARM_FINGERPRINT(ssn) ssn
  FROM `yourTable`
)
SELECT *
FROM `yourView`
WHERE ssn = FARM_FINGERPRINT('3234567890')
```

Below is implementation outline:
1. create yourView View in separate for yourTable Dataset
2. [authorize yourView View](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#authorized-views) as a reader for yourTable's dataset
3. so now, any user who has access to your view will be able to run below
4. of course, make sure your users do not have access to yourTable's dataset

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `yourView`
WHERE ssn = FARM_FINGERPRINT('3234567890')
```

and even if ssn is visible it is not real

Comment: It might be better to use `SHA256` or `SHA512` for this kind of use case to avoid hash collisions if security is important.

Comment: true. thanks for adding this. I was more focused on core idea for OP to get into right direction

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to expose only a subset of columns but to allow access to all of them if a filter is present. What if the filter was `ssn = ssn`, for instance? That would always be true unless `ssn` was null. You can, however, set up different datasets with different permissions and create views that expose some subset of columns in them. There is a good tutorial on [creating authorized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#authorized-views) in the BigQuery documentation.

For example, you could have:

- `restricted_dataset`: Only certain people in your team/organization can query or manage the tables and views in this dataset. Contains a table named `all_info` containing all data.
- `open_dataset`: Anyone in your team/organization can query tables/views in this dataset. Contains a view named `filtered_info` defined e.g. as `SELECT f_name, l_name FROM all_info;`